# Too big (in memory size) STL exports

Tags: export, blend-files, 3d-printing

I recently exported one of the Dota 2 characters after applying all the displacement masks to give all the skin and scale textures to the character.
The whole character was divided into 6 parts and each part has to b subdivided and then the displacement has to b applied to give better effects.
I worked on Pudge and after all the tweaking the stl file exported was of 1.8GB,
yeah GB, 
What to do , none of the 3D printing services around me are able to open or print the file , it taking too ling to even open and in most cases the 3D printer software crashes.

Even blender is not responding when importing the same stl file

[image: File made when exported with blender]

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the model, sounds like too high subdivision. Anyway if it is too big there is only one thing to do. SImplify the file.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a complicated mesh that was too big for blender. I ended up using [MeshLab](http://www.meshlab.net/) to simplify the mesh. It might be worth taking a shot. [Here](https://www.shapeways.com/tutorials/polygon_reduction_with_meshlab) is a tutorial on simplifying a mesh.

Answer (score 0):

`stl` file size is fundamentally proportional to the number of faces in your model (after implicit triangulation), so having a file that big means that your mesh has a huge amount of faces. It's either too finely detailed for a commercial 3D print, or many faces are redundant (unnecessary subdivision).

Before exporting the mesh, try using the **Decimate modifier**. Don't be afraid to decrease the *Ratio* to values as low as 0.05 (that in your case would yield a ~90 MB file). Just adjust that value to be the smallest possible that retains all the details that you care about (you can see the mesh updating live in the viewport).

After choosing the right "*Ratio*", apply the modifier and export.